# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseController'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

So I’m creating a small web app using Spring boot but when I run it I get this error “error creating bean with name `exerciseController`. I’ve separated my entities and controllers in separate packages. I also have three different packages for the web layer service layer, and the DAO layer but for some reason my app can’t create `exerciseController` I’ve already annotated the `exerciseController` class as a Controller. The exercise class has been annotated as an entity. I’ve also already autowired `ExerciseService` inside the controller class. It’s annotated as a repository in the DAO layer and annotated as a Service in the service layer. Even after all that it still can’t create the bean `exerciseController` for whatever reason.

More info: I’m using hibernate as my ORM and I’m also using the h2 database engine.

Thanks for the help!! :)

Here is some of my code

```
package com.omar.workoutlog;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My ExerciseController Class:

```
package com.omar.workoutlog.Controllers;
@Controller
public class ExerciseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseService exerciseService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showExercise(){


        return "workout";
    }

}
```

My ExerciseServiceImpl :

```
package com.omar.workoutlog.Service;    
@Service
public class ExerciseServiceImpl implements ExerciseService {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseDao exerciseDao;

    @Override
    public List<Exercise> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Exercise findById(Long id) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Exercise exercise, MultipartFile file) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Exercise exercise) {

    }

    @Override
    public void toggleFavorite(Exercise exercise) {

    }

    @Override
    public String findByExercisename(int week) {
        return exerciseDao.getExerciseName(week);
    }
}
```

If you need to see more code just let me know

Here is the full stack trace :

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'exerciseService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'exerciseDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/omar/workoutlog/Config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.omar.workoutlog.Application.main(Application.java:19) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'exerciseDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/omar/workoutlog/Config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'exerciseImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/omar/workoutlog/Config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/omar/workoutlog/Config/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorH2DatabaseImpl.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Wrong user name or password [28000-191])
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2293) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1532) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-191]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:143) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:448) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:329) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar:1.4.191]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:255) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2303) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289) ~[tomcat-dbcp-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 76 common frames omitted

:bootRun FAILED
```

Here is my DataConfig class:

```
    package com.omar.logbook.Config;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
@PropertySource("app.properties")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        Resource config = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(config);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("logbook1.entity.package"));
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

        // Driver class name
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("logbook1.db.driver"));

        // Set URL
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("logbook1.db.url"));

        // Set username & password
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("logbook1.db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("logbook1.db.password"));

        return ds;
    }
}
```

Here is my app.properties file:

```
workoutlog.entity.package = com.omar.workoutlog.model

workoutlog.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
workoutlog.db.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/Documents/workoutlog/data/workoutlog
workoutlog.db.username = sa
workoutlog.db.password =
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set naming strategy -->
        <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl</property>

        <!-- Update the database schema (structure) on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please add the package name of each class in the question, also the  complete stack trace that you get from your spring boot app.

Comment: Hey so I've made the edits to the question like you've asked let me know if you see where I went wrong and thanks for the help!

Comment: very good stacktrace. the stacktrace is telling you that username or password of the database are invalid just make sure that the h2 database configuration is defined on application. properties

Comment: You can also share the `DataConfig.class` to the question it will help to clarify exactly where is the mismatch in the configuration.  Also are you using application.properties file?  or the configuration is defined at the `DataConfig.class` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log information the exception that you get is the following:

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'
defined in class path resource [com/omar/workoutlog/Config/DataConfig.class


Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-191]
```

Let's validate that `com.omar.workoutlog.Config.DataConfig` has defined correctly all the properties to establish a connection to the H2 database.  Here is one example of how create the `DataSoruce` bean.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:testDb");
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

Comment: Okay so you were right there was a problem with the H2 database. The jar file did not match what I had in my Gradle once I matched them everything ran smoothly thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving controller package names in SpringBootApplication annotation like below

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.test.dashboard" }, scanBasePackageClasses = {
    com.test.dashboard.controller.DashboardPageController.class })
```